# I want to add the date to my log file

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, config, svcutil.exe

Log files can get very big, very fast if you log wcf calls and messages. I want to split up the log files by date. I can write my own tracelistener but i prefer some constant in the log if that is possible. Something like this

```
<sharedListener>
 <add initilizeDate="SomeLogFile{TODAY}.log"
```

this would output a log file like this : SomeLogFile2009-12-01

how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html), or implement your own TraceListener. Log4Net has RollingFileAppender, which does exactly that (it can roll files by date and/or size)

Comment: Thx for your reply. I edited my post: I prefer some constant in the log if that is possible

Comment: What do you mean by constant? That the log will be rolled each day and have the date in the filename?